# ODP.NET dont see reference to OracleAQQueue

Tags: c#, oracle, .net-6.0, odp.net

I use .NET 6 and have the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core package installed, version 3.21.120. (Clear .net console app) I would like to use AQ queues in my code but I do not see a reference to OracleAQQueue.

Any tips what should i do ?